# How to create Laravel-5.2 project beta version under public directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-5

I have been trying to create beta version of my live laravel-5.2 project in **public/beta** directory and have played alot with **.htaccess** file but in vain . please somebody help me out.

Here is my **.htaccess** file

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Comment: What exactly do you wish to use this **public/beta** directory for?

Comment: I have a project  and want to create exact copy of project in public/beta directory for development phase because the project is already live and i can't take risk to manage it on live. one more thing ,i  have copied project source to public/beta and made some changes in .htaccess and it works fine on localhost but fails on live server.

Comment: Why don't you create a new folder like **beta** for example, and point another virtual host into **beta/public** and maybe have it on a subdomain instead?

Comment: I want it on same ip , here is the live project link 159.203.170.74/ and i want to create beta like this 159.203.170.74/beta/ . any help would be appreciated